# SwiftUI: How to prevent Button shifting when above text disappears/appears

Tags: user-interface, swiftui

Currently, I'm using Combine for textField Validation. However, when the alert text disappears/appears, the Submit button below will be shifting. Is there any way to prevent this behavior ( without giving it a fixed frame size)?

[image]

Here is my code

TextField and prompt

```
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {    
            TextField("", text: $text)
                .font(.system(.title2, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(.blue)

        Text(prompt)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .font(.caption)
        }
```

ContentView

```
                VStack(spacing: 15) {
                    FloatingTextField(placeHolder : "First name", text: $userVM.firstName, borderColor: $color, prompt: userVM.confirmFnamePrompt)
                    FloatingTextField(placeHolder : "Last Name", text: $userVM.lastName, borderColor: $color, prompt: userVM.confirmLnamePrompt)
                        .padding(.bottom, 400)
                }
                Spacer()
                Button {

                } label: {
                    Text("Submit")                            
                }
                .disabled(!userVM.isFieldValid)
```

Comment: If you know the prompt will always just be one line of text, you could always keep *something* in the prompt and then just manipulate the `opacity`

Comment: Oh thats true, this is a good solution. Thank you @jnpdx

Comment: I think it is enough to get rid of `.padding(.bottom, 400)` (as there is Spacer)